# What approaches could I use to convert an Azure B2C token for an online game into a "take a break" reminder?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, microsoft-identity-platform, appinsights

I'd like to configure at the issuer level a way to see if an authentication token has been renewed that a redirect screen will appear to remind (or enforce) a cool off period, for example if I were playing Age of Empires, Civilization, or Sim City online I would need something like that to save my game (with just one more turn...).

- Is there any way I can determine when a OIDC session expiration occurs, and/or an OAuth resource token needs renewal, has been renewed?
- Could a B2C Function app read an AppInsights (or some other log) to offer mental health reminders (or a variety of other things for a better life) in the form of a `loading...` page? (Like the Apple iOS launch screen guidelines, but created an extension of identity and privacy)

Answer (score 0):

When doing a silent token call, the auth_time claim is updated. So each time you call an API, make a silent token call and compare the auth_time claim with the last stored auth_time claim. If they are different, a token renewal occurred. You can freely call for silent tokens with MSAL, and it’ll only obtain a new token if the one in the cache has expired.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look and see if the auth_time is logged and if it's possible to configure B2C to refuse to renew a silent token call until an authenticated HTTP browser flow is initiated.